# Pantheon Live / Test / Dev Login Issue

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I have recently inherited a Drupal 7 site on Pantheon.io. None of the admin logins that work flawlessly in the Live environment work in either Test or Dev. I have pushed/pulled code and DB between the three to make sure they are all identical, but the logins still fail in Test and Dev. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using Drush to log in?

Comment: I am not familiar with Drush, I will take a look there now.

Comment: running **'terminus drush <site>.<env> uli "user name"'** prompts me for my dashboard password then generates a password-reset link on the Drupal site. When I put in a new password and confirm it, I get "Error message
Access denied. You may need to login below or register to access this page."

Answer (score 1):

After more hours than I care to admit, I came to realize that the issue was very simple... The Pantheon Dashboard's links to "site admin" go to the `http://` site and NOT the `https://` site, therefore, none of the addresses were resolving correctly. The live site automatically redirects `http://` traffic to `https://` so it works just fine.